# Migration from 5.22.0 to 6.0.0, jobExecutorActivate flag missing

Tags: activiti

I'm trying to migrate from 5.22.0 to 6.0.0. Seems that property of `org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration`, or actually `org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl` named jobExecutorActivate was moved. The current documentation doesn't mention how to migrate this part.

Does anybody know how to migrate it correctly?

Sample configuration:

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know already. It was removed completely:

`The async executor of Activiti 5 is the only available job executor in Activiti 6 as it is a more performant and more database friendly way of executing asynchronous jobs in the Activiti Engine. The old job executor of Activiti 5 is removed. More information can be found in the advanced section of the user guide.`
[From activiti userguide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#jobExecutorConfiguration).

So the correct flag now is `asyncExecutorActivate`

```
    <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true" />
```

Also if you ended here by any chance looking for differences between the async and old executor please refer to [advanced part of the guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_async_executor).